# Create ultra-restricted account in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions, user-accounts, steadystate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a Windows User Acount that can not change anything?](https://superuser.com/questions/62929/how-to-make-a-windows-user-acount-that-can-not-change-anything)

I need to share my PC with friends and I want to create a new user account for them with specific requirements that go as follows:

1. They should only be able access specific programs(Browser and its plugins, antivirus, task manager etc.). Start menu should not show any other programs
2. They should have write access only to their profile(Desktop etc)
3. The profile should reset upon logoff(similar to windows 7 guest mode)
4. They should only be able to shut down/log off(no hibernate/stand by etc)
5. Read access to specific folders ONLY(no read access to any partition as a whole)
6. They should be able add torrents from magnet links to uTorrent(this seems quite opposite to no-write-access elsewhere policy but still if there is any workaround)
7. Internet access over LAN

What I have tried(or considered):

1. Combination of Windows 7 guest mode(not guest account) and parental controls - but guest mode has been removed from final version of windows 7
2. Regarding uTorrent, I have configured it to load torrents automatically from a folder - what about magnet links?
3. Windows SteadyState works fine but it is for XP only. Furthermore, I am worried that  setting up drive protection in windows steadystate will conflict with windows 7 drive access on my dual boot(XP and 7) machine.

I would like to avoid using third-party tools as far as posible.
Kindly suggest a possible solution to create such a locked down user account.

P.S. I have my own administrator account.

Comment: C'mon guys...I earned tumbleweed for this... :P

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try all the suggestions.

However, you can deny usage of particular drive:

1. Right-click on any drive to change permissions
2. Go to seccurity tab
3. edit
4. Deny permissions to any specified users
5. Apply
6. OK

Comment: That wouldn't fix the problem (make the ultra-restricted account)